# Are there any disadvantages to using a separate Apple ID for the Apple Developer programs and personal use?

Tags: app-store

I would like to enroll in one of [Apple's Developer programs](https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/standard/). I don't have a company, so my “enrollment type” would be “individual.” While I already have an Apple ID that I use to buy music, apps etc. in iTunes, Apple suggest you may want to create a new Apple ID for the developer program (the [first page in the enrollment process](https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/standard/create.php) says “Create an Apple ID - 
Select this option if you don’t have an Apple ID or need to create a new Apple ID because you:
Would like an Apple ID dedicated to business transactions with Apple”). I think I would prefer to do it this way.

But I'm wondering whether there are any disadvantages to using separate Apple IDs like this on the same Mac (one for the development, one for personal use in iTunes and the App Store)?

As a side question, I also don't fully understand the relationship between an Apple ID and an Apple Developer Account. Is a Developer Account always tied to an Apple ID? Or can it be transferred to another Apple ID (say you start a company and want to transfer the ownership of the account to the company)?